# Как перекинуть переменную из функции в главный файл?

Tags: c

Мне необходимо перекинуть переменную `Ti` из функции в главный файл. Если оставить все как есть в моем коде, то `Ti` будет равна 0 (в главном файле). Каким образом можно эту переменную перекинуть?

Вот кусок из главного файла где я вызываю функцию для расчета переменной `Ti`

```
float Uinp[n],Uout[n],Ti;
raschet_Ti(Uout,n,Uinp1,t0,dt,Ti);
printf("\nImpulse time: [%f] ",Ti);
```

А вот сама функция

```
void raschet_Ti(float Uout[],int n,float Uinp1,int t0,float dt,float Ti)
{

   int i,J;
   float Umax,Tpz,Tpp,U1,U;
   setlocale(LC_ALL,"RUS");
   Umax = 0;
   for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
   {
       if(Umax < Uout[i])
       {
         Umax=Uout[i];
         J=i;

       }
   }
   U1=0.5*Umax;
   i=1;
   while(Uout[i]<U1)
   {
     i++;
   }
    Tpp=t0+i*dt;

    i=J;
    while(Uout[i]>U1)
   {
     i++;
   }
    Tpz=t0+i*dt;
    Ti=Tpz-Tpp;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как Ваша функция рассчитывает Ti, то пусть она его и возвращает. Где то так

```
float raschet_Ti(float Uout[],int n,float Uinp1,int t0,float dt)
{
    // удалил, что бы не мешало
    Tpz=t0+i*dt;
    return Tpz-Tpp;

}
```

и вызов

```
float Uinp[n],Uout[n],Ti;
Ti = raschet_Ti(Uout,n,Uinp1,t0,dt);
printf("\nImpulse time: [%f] ",Ti);
```

Можно конечно передать Ti по указателю, но здесь это не нужно.

```
void raschet_Ti(float Uout[],int n,float Uinp1,int t0,float dt,float* Ti)
{
// удалил, что бы не мешало примеру
    Tpz=t0+i*dt;
    *Ti=Tpz-Tpp;

}
```

ну и вызываем так

```
float Uinp[n],Uout[n],Ti;
raschet_Ti(Uout,n,Uinp1,t0,dt,&Ti);
printf("\nImpulse time: [%f] ",Ti);
```